# How to add material design to all components from Angular 2?

Tags: angular, material-design

I implemented a project with material design and angular 2. I imported module for material design, added the theme. My app have only main module. Material design is applied only im main component (and his child component), not on all secondary components. 
Please, can you help me to find a solution for this issue? 
[You can see that I have 2 components. One of them have material design applied and the other one no.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8jpC.png)

Comment: You should be including material design with a `<style>` tag in your index.html instead of in your component

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorry, but I don't understand exactly how to include material design for angular 2 with a style tag in index.html  I only put this for theme, but it doesn't work  <link href="../node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.css" rel="stylesheet"> Please, can you prove more details?

Comment: take a look at one of the sample apps in the material site https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview or their theming guide https://material.angular.io/guide/theming